# On Safari, Google is showing some flag symbol

Tags: safari, imac, google

On my iMac --> Safari, open google search engine.

On home page I seen flag type symbol. When I try to click on that nothing happens.

Want to know what the indicates ?

Here is image : [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Apple hardware or software as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: @fsb Why ? Under `Ask Different` logo written that ask about `Apple hardware and software`, and `Safari` is Apple's software right ?

Comment: Because Google controls what's displayed on the screen, not Apple.  Following your explanation, any page that's displayed in Safari is, therefore, Apple's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the [LGBT pride flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag_(LGBT_movement)). Presumably from your [Google India](https://www.google.co.in/) URL. This is in relation to the [recent decriminalisation of homosexual intercourse by the Indian Supreme Court](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-45429664).